# how can i use a function as a props in the child component using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

am triying to make a simple tik-tak-toe game using react, but  i have some problem in my code.

This is the parent component :

```
const Wrapper = () => {
         
   const [cases, setCases] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
   const [isX, setIsX] = useState(true);

   const handleClick = (i) => {
        cases[i] = isX ? 'X' : 'O';
        setCases(cases);
        setIsX(!isX);
        console.log(cases)
   }
    
    return ( 
        <div className='ttt-wrapper'>
            <div className='ttt-3-cols'>
                <Case value={cases[0]} onClick={()=> handleClick(0)}/>
                <Case value={cases[1]} onClick={()=> handleClick(1)}/>
                <Case value={cases[2]} onClick={()=> handleClick(2)}/>
            </div>
            <div className='ttt-3-cols'>
                <Case value={cases[3]} onClick={()=> handleClick(3)}/>
                <Case value={cases[4]} onClick={()=> handleClick(4)}/>
                <Case value={cases[5]} onClick={()=> handleClick(5)}/>
            </div>
            <div className='ttt-3-cols'>
                <Case value={cases[6]} onClick={()=> handleClick(6)}/>
                <Case value={cases[7]} onClick={()=> handleClick(7)}/>
                <Case value={cases[8]} onClick={()=> handleClick(8)}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the child component :

```
const Case = ({ value, handleClick }) => {
   console.log(value)
  return (
    <button className='ttt-case' onClick={handleClick} >
        { value }
     </button>
  )
}
```

How can i use the `handleClick` function inside  so i can use the click ?

Comment: pass it as any other prop .... `<Case value={cases[0]} handleClick={handleClick} />`

Comment: i know it work usually like that, but it does not working

Comment: not sure how it didn't work ... you have not passed it as prop at all in above code and don't mutate the array like you did

Comment: i updated my code, and if you can see, i added a console.log and the props, but when i click the console log does not show anthing

Comment: You invoke the Case component with the props `onClick` instead `handleClick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution :

```
const Wrapper = () => {
         
   const [cases, setCases] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
   const [isX, setIsX] = useState(true);

   const handleClick = (i) => {
        cases[i] = isX ? 'X' : 'O';
        setCases(cases);
        setIsX(!isX);
        console.log(cases)
   }
    
    return ( 
        <div className='ttt-wrapper'>
            <div className='ttt-3-cols'>
                <Case value={cases[0]} onClick={()=> handleClick(0)}/>
                <Case value={cases[1]} onClick={()=> handleClick(1)}/>
                <Case value={cases[2]} onClick={()=> handleClick(2)}/>
            </div>
            <div className='ttt-3-cols'>
                <Case value={cases[3]} onClick={()=> handleClick(3)}/>
                <Case value={cases[4]} onClick={()=> handleClick(4)}/>
                <Case value={cases[5]} onClick={()=> handleClick(5)}/>
            </div>
            <div className='ttt-3-cols'>
                <Case value={cases[6]} onClick={()=> handleClick(6)}/>
                <Case value={cases[7]} onClick={()=> handleClick(7)}/>
                <Case value={cases[8]} onClick={()=> handleClick(8)}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Case component  :

```
  const Case = ({ value, onClick }) => {      return (
        <button className='ttt-case' onClick={onClick}>
            { value }
         </button>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `handleClick` like this:

```js
const Case = ({ value, handleClick }) => {
   console.log(value)
  return (
    <button className='ttt-case' onClick={()=>handleClick(value)} >
        { value }
     </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: but what doo you put in the `<Wrapper />`  ah props ? and this code is not working, i have this error : Uncaught TypeError: handleClick is not a function

Comment: you can pass ` <Case value={cases[6]} onClick={handleClick}/>`

Comment: i updated my code, the click does not working, even with the console log i added

Answer (score 0):

```
const Wrapper = () => {
         
   const [cases, setCases] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
   const [isX, setIsX] = useState(true);

   const handleClick = (i) => {
        const newCases = [...cases];  //making a copy
        newCases[i] = isX ? 'X' : 'O';   // I'm not sure what is the logic here tbh
        setCases(newCases);
        setIsX(x=>!x); // updater function
   }
    
    return ( 
        <div className='ttt-wrapper'>
            <div className='ttt-3-cols'>
                <Case value={cases[0]} handleClick={handleClick}/>
                <Case value={cases[1]} handleClick={handleClick}/>
                <Case value={cases[2]} handleClick={handleClick}/>
            </div>
            <div className='ttt-3-cols'>
                <Case value={cases[3]} handleClick={handleClick}/>
                <Case value={cases[4]} handleClick={handleClick}/>
                <Case value={cases[5]} handleClick={handleClick}/>
            </div>
            <div className='ttt-3-cols'>
                <Case value={cases[6]} handleClick={handleClick}/>
                <Case value={cases[7]} handleClick={handleClick}/>
                <Case value={cases[8]} handleClick={handleClick}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const Case = ({ value, handleClick }) => {
   console.log(value)
  return (
    <button className='ttt-case' onClick={()=>handleClick(value)} >
        { value }
     </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: not like this actually, you pass onClick as props but it is not used

Comment: I didn't pass `onClick` as props at all .... its `handleClick`